# Get border elements from list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am looking for a concise way to get a list of all border elements (explanation follows) from a list of lists **without** the use of any external package (e.g. `numpy`).

#### Definition: border element

A border element is either:

- An element from the first or last list
- First or last element of a list

#### Example

Assume following list of lists:

```
a = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
```

#### Expected output

The expected output is a list of border elements, order does not really play a role. So following is a valid result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 14, 15, 16, 5, 9, 8, 12]
```

#### Current approach

Currently I am doing the following:

```
border = a[0] + a[-1] + [x[0] for x in a[1:-1]] + [x[-1] for x in a[1:-1]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 14, 15, 16, 5, 9, 8, 12]
```

The code works fine, but I wonder if there is a more compact form? Especially, I have a feeling that the two list comprehensions (to get first and last elements from 2nd to 2nd last lists) can be combined.

Comment: what is border elements?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by border element

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: How is it `[1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 14, 15, 16, 5, 8, 8, 12]`? Isn't it supposed to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 14, 15, 16, 5, 8, 9, 12]`? How come there are two 8s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out a slightly shorter solution

```
a[0] + a[-1] + [y for x in a[1:-1] for y in [x[0],x[-1]]]
```

Comment: Even more compact: `a[0] + a[-1] + [x[i] for x in a[1:-1] for in (0,-1)]`. But pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `list comprehension`:

```
a= [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]

border = [item for sublist in [lst if i == 0 or i == len(a)-1 else [lst[0],lst[-1]] for i, lst in enumerate(a)] for item in sublist]
```

Output:

```
>>> border
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: I asked for a *more compact* form. Appreciate your answer, but this does not fit my requirements.

Comment: Do u want it to be shorter?

Comment: That's what I'm asking for, yes.

Comment: Why don't u define a function and add this code there? Then u can call that function from ur code. Ur code would look a lot cleaner.

Comment: It's not about coding style, it's about a compact way of doing things.

Comment: Ok...I don't think that there is a shorter way of doing it. But I will try to figure out one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will satisfy you :

```
[item for sublist in [[i[0], i[-1]] for i in a] + [i[1:-1] for i in [a[0], a[-1]]] for item in sublist]
```

Comment: I asked for a more compact form. Appreciate your answer, but this does not fit my requirements.